# How to send a file to the browser using ASP.NET MVC controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-io

I have an application where I allow my users to upload a file of any type.  I save this in the file system on the server.  The application will only be accessed by two users, so I don't need to worry about uploading any dodgy files.

How do I allow my user to press a button on an MVC form to request the file be sent back via the browser and be presented with the standard save/open dialog?

I want to return any type of file, and the example I've found always specify the type of file being returned.  Is there a simple example of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx) and derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to set [HttpContext.Response.ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype.aspx) to the proper mimetype and then writing the contents of the file with HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write ().

Useful if, for example, the data is not in a local file but stored in a database as a binary blob.